# Express-validator does not return any errors when validating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to validate user input when they register and test if there are errors produced in `express-validator` before saving it into the database. I am expecting that there are errors produced when I submit an empty form or whenever I fill in something that doesn't match the expected input (say email must be a valid email). However, after multiple attempts, and checking different questions that have been posted previously, I still do not understand why the middleware isn't working.

**Code for `routes/index.js`**

```
app.post('/signup', authenticated, userController.validateNewUser, (req, res) => { // Validate temp
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(errors);
  console.log(errors.array());
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     return res.send( {errors: errors.array(), message: "Error"} );
  } else {
     // this gets executed since there are no errors apparently
     return res.send( {message: "OK"} );
  }   
});
```

Note: I do have a `const{validationResult} = require('express-validator');` above the file.

**Code for `userController.validateNewUser`in `controllers/userController.js`**

```
validateNewUser: [
  body('firstName')
  .exists()
  .not().isEmpty().withMessage('Cannot be empty')
  .isLength({ min:2, max:20 }).withMessage('First Name must be between 2 to 20 letters.')
  .isAlpha().withMessage('First Name must contain letters.'),

  body('lastName')
  .exists()
  .not().isEmpty()
  .isLength({ min:2, max:20 }).withMessage('Last Name must be between 2 to 20 letters')
  .isAlpha().withMessage('Last Name must contain letters.'),

  body('email')
  .exists()
  .not().isEmpty()
  .isEmail().withMessage('Email must be a valid email.'),
]
```

Note: I do have a `const{body} = require('express-validator');` above the file.

**OUTPUT**
When executing the code, filling the form with empty fields, it produces no error:

```
{
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: ''
}
Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }
[]
```

Even when I fill in something (`req.body` is not empty), it doesn't produce any errors:

```
{
  firstName: 'fllllllllllllllllllllllll',
  lastName: 'k',
  email: '',
  password: 'dd',
  confirmPassword: 'ddd'
}
Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }
[]
```

Unlike previous questions, which were either due to not including a `validationResult(req)` to fetch the errors or the `check` middleware not being used appropriately, the code does actually go through the entire validation process but captures no error. It runs fine and produces no error at all actually. I currently have no idea what might be causing this and how to fix it. It was working previously, but after changing a bit of the code, it stopped working for some reason.

Comment: you probably need to set `validateNewUser = []` not `:` and then `module.export` or do whatever you want

Comment: @SwapnilSoni It's a `:` because it's inside a `module.export = {}`. I don't think the problem arises from there... The validation part in `validateNewUser` still executes; if I were to write `.not().isEmpty` without the parentheses, it would throw me an error since it doesn't recognize `.isEmpty`.

Comment: Hello, here is my github, for a complete example on how I am using express-validator. You can check the routes and how the project is structured. https://github.com/danizavtz/tokenAuth @EmilyChiu

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working validation example.

In my example I used a `notEmpty()` [function](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#notempty).

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationBodyRules = [
    body('login', 'login is required').exists(),
    body('password', 'password is required').exists(),
    body('login', 'login is required').notEmpty(),
    body('password', 'password is required').notEmpty()
];

exports.checkRules = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    next();
};
```

Here is my router function for validation chaining.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginService = require('../controllers/login.controller');
const loginValidator = require('../validators/login.validator');

router.post('/login', loginValidator.validationBodyRules, loginValidator.checkRules, loginService.hashPassword, loginService.lookupLogin, loginService.logEmployee);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Even when using `.notEmpty()`, it doesn't save any errors in `const errors` @Danizavtz , it's still empty...